# Showing two tori are non-isomorphic as complex manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, elliptic-curves

I want to show that there exist two elliptic curves over $\Bbb C$ that are non-isomorphic.

Let us write $\Gamma_1=\Bbb{Z}\oplus \Bbb{Z}\tau_1$ and $\Gamma_2=\Bbb{Z}\oplus\Bbb{Z}\tau_2$ where $\tau_1,\tau_2\in\Bbb C\backslash\Bbb R$ and $\tau_2\not\in\Bbb{R}\{\tau_1\}$, and consider two elliptic curves $X=\Bbb{C}/\Gamma_1$ and $Y=\Bbb{C}/\Gamma_2$.

(Or in words: Let $\Gamma_1,\Gamma_2$ be non-equivalent rank two $\Bbb{Z}$-lattices in $\Bbb C$. In particular let it be so that $\operatorname{SL}_2(\Bbb Z)\cdot \Gamma_1\not\ni\Gamma_2$.)

Clearly $X,Y$ are topologically equivalent to a torus (and hence one-another).

I want to distinguish the two of these as complex manifolds. Could someone tell me how to do this by means of `periods'? Apparently period integrals can take us back to the lattice, and this distinguishes them, but I don't understand this theory yet.

Comment: $Y=\Bbb{C}/\Gamma_1$ is bi-holomorphically equivalent to $Y=\Bbb{C}/\Gamma_2$ iff there exists $\alpha \in \Bbb C^*$ such that $\Gamma_1=\alpha \Gamma_2$. See problem 5.4 on page 39 of Otto Forster's book Lectures on Riemann Surfaces.

Comment: If you want I can give you a solution of this fact.

Comment: @UserS I suppose I have proven one direction of this. That is, $\Bbb{C}/\Gamma$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{C}/\alpha\Gamma$ for $\alpha\in \Bbb C^\times$. But I wanted to exhibit two non-isomorphic elliptic curves with proof. So I suppose showing the other direction would allow me to do this trivially

Comment: Miranda addresses the problem in Algebraic Curves and Riemann Surfaces. Pages 62-65